# How to stop Code executing once I catch an exception?

Tags: apex, api, exception

I am attempting to display an error message on a VF page if I get a time out error from an api call. I am using try catch, to get to the exception, but I would like to stop further code execution after.

Controller:

```
    try{
        gmsSearchResults = GMSServiceAPI.doAdvancedSearch(cfg); //perform the call

     }catch (CalloutException e){

         if(e.getMessage() == 'Read timed out'){

                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ' We have a timeout Error. GMS did not return results for the allotted time.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
         }
     }

if(gmsSearchResults.size() > 49){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, ' Search returned more than 50 records. Please refine your search criteria.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
        }
```

I am seeing the exception and the error in my debug log, but the rest of my code fails when it hits the if statement outside of the try/catch, with an error of "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a return statement.

```
catch (CalloutException e)
{
    // handle error
    return;
}
```

If your method return type is `PageReference` rather than `void`, then change `return` to `return null`.